# How to open a specific URL when an app bar item(overlay) is clicked in Android application

Tags: android, appbar

I have created custom app bar , with some action items. like Skype and Facebook icon . What i want is to open the the respective web page upon that item clicked.
Java class code here:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id=item.getItemId();
    if(id==R.id.action_item1){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"FB call not available yet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (id==R.id.action_item2){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Skype  not available yet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if (id==R.id.action_item3){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," chat not available yet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"call menu selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without an example of your code we really can't get very far.

However, if the menu items in your appbar are set using a menu.xml file, you can use the id reference of a menu item in the onMenuItemSelected to open a webpage for your social media menu items.

Comment: sir i've updated my post with relevant code.can you elaborate how to to open a webpage for your social media menu items.

Comment: You're on the right track, @Munir 's implementation should do what you're looking for. Cheers.